# Using a WebBrowser Control Inside a C# Winforms Dialog Box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dialog

I'm currently trying to implement a HTML viewer in a simple pop-up dialog window (No user interaction, just displaying formatted text).

When called, it throws a '**ThreadStateException**'. As far as I can find, this can be fixed by appending *[STAThread]* to the main entry point of the program, but this is **not** currently an option available.

The code to create the WebBrowser dialog is:

```
    public static void ShowUserHTMLDialog(string formTitle, string formLabel, int formWidth, int formHeight, string html)
    {
        var webBrowser = new WebBrowser();

        var form = CreateBasicForm(formTitle, formLabel, formWidth, formHeight);

        webBrowser.Name = "webWindow";
        webBrowser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(formWidth, formHeight - 70);
        webBrowser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 35);
        webBrowser.AllowWebBrowserDrop = false;

        webBrowser.DocumentText = html;

        form.Controls.Add(webBrowser);

        DialogResult windowResult = form.ShowDialog();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Test program for various dialogs defined in class library.

        string html = "<h1>Test Window</h1>"
            + "<p>This is some more text.</p>"
            + "<ul>"
            + "<li>Item 1</li>"
            + "<li>Item 2</li>"
            + "</ul>";

        Dialog.ShowUserHTMLDialog("TEST", "TEST", 640, 480, html);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution:

```
    public static bool ShowUserHTMLDialog(string formTitle, string formLabel, int formWidth, int formHeight, string html)
    {
        DialogResult formResult = DialogResult.Abort;

        var thread = new Thread
            (
                () =>
                {
                    var webBrowser = new WebBrowser();

                    var form = CreateBasicForm(formTitle, formLabel, formWidth, formHeight);

                    webBrowser.Name = "webWindow";
                    webBrowser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(formWidth, formHeight - 70);
                    webBrowser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 35);
                    webBrowser.AllowWebBrowserDrop = false;

                    webBrowser.DocumentText = html;

                    form.Controls.Add(webBrowser);

                    formResult = form.ShowDialog();
                }
            );
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();

        return (formResult == DialogResult.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just create a own form which uses those parameters and open it (dunno what you meant with label)^^

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(string formTitle, string formLabel, int formWidth, int formHeight, string html)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Text = formTitle;
        Width = formWidth;
        Height = formHeight;
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
    }
}
```

calling it like this (show or showdialog, depends on you ^^)

```
new Form2("title", "label", 1000, 1000, "<h1>Test Window</h1>"
        + "<p>This is some more text.</p>"
        + "<ul>"
        + "<li>Item 1</li>"
        + "<li>Item 2</li>"
        + "</ul>").Show();
```

**edit**

webbrowser is added trough dragging the control onto the form ^^

**edit again**
like this sry ^^

```
        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            new Form1("title", "label", 1000, 1000, "<h1>Test Window</h1>"
                + "<p>This is some more text.</p>"
                + "<ul>"
                + "<li>Item 1</li>"
                + "<li>Item 2</li>"
                + "</ul>").ShowDialog();
        });
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: How is the webBrowser1 initialised? That's where I'm encountering the error.

Comment: Is there a way to create the thread within the dialog method? So there's no need to create a new thread whenever calling the dialog?

Comment: it is propably not possible because you need to invoke it from the thread you create and than it isn't in the correct Apartment State (atleast i dont know of a way o do so)

Comment: It is possible, see my submitted answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem and thanks too for telling me a working solution ^^